# Is SSD a safe replacement for HDD image storage?

Tags: storage, file-format, computer-hardware, editing

Every small M.2 SSD (solid-state drives) is increasingly replacing HDD (hard disk drives) in new PCs for file storage.

SSD is proven to be better for image editing, but what about image storage? Is a PC with 2 SSDs (1 for editing, 1 for storage) better than a PC with 1 HDD (for storage) and 1 SSD (for editing)?

In terms of your valuable image files being safe from data loss, corruption or fragmentation. For the purpose of safe storage.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about storage durability and not about photography.

Comment: Remember the adage… "Any data not stored in at least three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary."

Comment: Very funny. Two people vote to close this question, but a mod actually answers this question without actually closing it.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya why is that funny? I think this question is only barely on-topic. People are obviously going to have different opinions. With due respect to the mods here, just because they are mods doesn't mean they are infallible.

Comment: I think it would also be helpful if you mentioned maybe why your research hasn't answered this question for you. I researched it myself not too long ago, so I know there is information out there on this.

Comment: To add to @Tetsujin's adage, I always keep in mind that there are just 2 types of data storage devices... storage devices that are going to fail...and storage devices that have already failed.

Comment: Aside: I would be more worried if people never disagreed with me than if they do - that would be the sign of a broken community where people don't feel safe to express their opinions to the "people in power".

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this question is _marginally_ on-topic. "How should I ensure my digital photos are secure" is (as a general topic) something photographers should worry about - but obsessing about the details of magnetic vs SSD is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The main reason why you probably want to store large amounts (!) of images (or any data) on HDDs rather than SSDs is that with HDDs you get more storage space for the same money.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is always the same: you should never rely on having just one copy of anything important. Any difference in reliability between magnetic drives and SSDs is essentially irrelevant - they are both "good enough" if you have independent copies.

"Independent" copies is its own can of worms - having two SSDs in your house with the photos on is of no value if your house burns down. Having a copy "in the cloud" is potentially of no value if your cloud provider goes bust. And how are you going to protect yourself from "fat finger disease" and deleting the wrong files?

Worry about all that before you worry about the difference between magnetic disks and SSDs.

Answer (score 6):

While all the comments about the backup and X-Y problem are absolutely correct, I'll still try to answer the question directly. "Other things being equal", so to speak.

1. SSDs are primarily known and valued for speed of data access. This is rarely a consideration for a photo archive. Thus, no advantage here.
2. SSD is much more limited by write cycles. However, if you use this disk just to dump your photos, it won't be a practical limitation. Not much disadvantage.
3. SSDs are still much more expensive, particularly for large capacities. If your photo archive is several TB like mine, HDD is the only practical option.
4. There are reasons to believe SSD degrades significantly quicker, particularly when it's unpowered and can't apply its self-recovery and levelling algorithms. The [JDEC standard](https://www.jedec.org/sites/default/files/Alvin_Cox%20%5BCompatibility%20Mode%5D_0.pdf) specifies only one year of data retention<sup>1</sup> for consumer SSDs at 30°C (this figure halves for each 5°C!) In contrast, HDDs are known to last for decades, as long as they are kept away from strong magnetic fields.<sup>2</sup> On the other hand, HDDs are naturally more fragile. Thus, for this usage case (long-term [mostly] offline storage), HDD appear to be superior.
5. SSDs are notoriously difficult for emergency data recovery. Basically, if it's dead, or you accidentally deleted the last copy of a file, you can consider it gone. In contrast, HDDs *can* sometimes be recovered, even when they appear dead.<sup>3</sup> Needless to say, the investment into this will likely be greater than in a timely back-up. Still, a point to HDD - as long as it doesn't foster complacency about back-ups.

So, overall, *I believe* the optimal configuration for larger photo archives is SSD for work + large HDD (5+ TB) for the operative storage + one or more offline portable 3.5" 2-5 TB HDD for periodic syncronisation, + favourite off-site storage method (similar portable HDDs or cloud). But if your archive is under 1 TB, the operative storage (in the computer) can be SSD - but preferably *separate* SSD from the main one.

---

<sup>1</sup> This should not be interpreted that it will fail after a year, or that it's half-life. It just means the probability/quantity of errors on the drive will exceed a defined acceptable level. Also, most current drives likely exceed this requirement.

<sup>2</sup> I personally have a 20 y.o. drive that is perfectly readable. The challenge is rather to find an IDE interface.

<sup>3</sup> I did it once by swapping the controllers with an identical drive, and have seen other successful cases.